# Memory warning while load image in UIImageView in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a viewController with an UIImageView, I change image when slide with Swipe.

While I change some images, I received memory warnings and App crash sometimes. Images have 300KB aprox...

I load images with:

```
 image1.image = UIImage(named: "myImage")!
```

How can resolve this? In Swift haven't release.. How can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Post the crash log please

Comment: Show Received memory warning. in Console. SomeTimes say Lost connection to iphone.. I think that this is for memory over but I don't know

Comment: It started with Xcode 6. I don't know why but frequently it gives memory warnings even when your app weights only 10 mb. I think it's one of new Xcode bugs. Eventually I gave up paying attention to these warnings

Comment: I'am checking memory in memory report and this show 198MB ... I'm confused, only load five different images in viewController. One image at time when detect swipe gesture

Comment: @user3745888 how do you check memory? with Instruments?

Comment: In left panel, show the Debug navigator

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is the Method,

```
[UIImage imageNamed: ];//In objective c
image1.image = UIImage(named: "myImage")! //in Swift
```

This itself is a very memory using method. instead of this use:

```
init?(contentsOfFile path: String)
```

Comment: This is incorrect. using the `UIImage(named:)` method returns a cached image.

Comment: I did say it returned a cached image.

Comment: While the link you point to is technically correct, you're missing the point. If you have images that are being used throughout your app, then putting then using the `named:` method is going to be useful, as it will only be keeping one cached copy of the image even if it is used multiple times. This is a good thing. Yes, the cache will grow, but it will be purged under memory pressure, all you need to do is to be sensible about is not keeping references to images that you don't need anymore.

Comment: @vishwa.deepak, calling people "ignorant" isn't very nice.